# Script that calls another script to execute on every file in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

There are two directories that contains these files:

First one /usr/local/nagios/etc/hosts

```
[root@localhost hosts]$  ll
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 apache nagios 1236 Feb  7 10:10 10.80.12.53.cfg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 apache nagios 1064 Feb 27 22:47 10.80.12.62.cfg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 apache nagios 1063 Feb 22 12:02 localhost.cfg
```

And the second one /usr/local/nagios/etc/services

```
[root@localhost services]$  ll
total 20
-rw-rw-r-- 1 apache nagios 2183 Feb 27 22:48 10.80.12.62.cfg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 apache nagios 1339 Feb 13 10:47 Check usage _etc.cfg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 apache nagios 7874 Feb 22 11:59 localhost.cfg
```

And I have a script that goes through file in Hosts directory and paste some lines from that file in the file in the Services directory.

The script is ran like this:

./nagios-contacts.sh /usr/local/nagios/etc/hosts/10.80.12.62.cfg /usr/local/nagios/etc/services/10.80.12.62.cfg

How can I achieve that another script calls my script and goes through every file in the Hosts directory and does its job for the files with the same name in the Service directory?

In my script I´m pulling out contacts from the 10.80.12.62.cfg in the Hosts directory and appending them to the file with the same name in the Service directory.

Comment: Have you tried.... a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `ls` output as an input to `for loop` instead use the built-in wild-cards. See [why](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) it's not a good idea.

```
for f in /usr/local/nagios/etc/hosts/*.cfg
do
  basef=$(basename "$f")
  ./nagios-contacts.sh "$f" "/usr/local/nagios/etc/services/${basef}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to do some iteration.

```
echo $(pwd)
for file in $(ls); do ./nagious-contacts.sh $file; done;
```

So it will loop over all files in the current directory.

You can also modify it as well by doing something more absolute.

```
abspath=$1
for file in $(ls $abspath); do ./nagious-contacts.sh $abspath/$file; done
```

which would loop over all files in a set directory, and then pass the abspath/filename into your script.

Comment: I can try that, but will it match the files with the same name from one to another directory? For 10.80.12.62.cfg in the Hosts directory, the script must be executed on 10.80.12.62.cfg in the service directory. :/

Comment: Try to avoid using `ls` output in `for loop`.